# Rolling average on uneven time series data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to do a rolling average over uneven time series data. Here's an example of what my data looks like:

```
4/22/2015   66.67802429
6/1/2015    65.99763489
6/13/2015   65.77084351
6/15/2015   67.81231386
6/17/2015   65.0904541
6/24/2015   66.9048233
7/5/2015    65.77084351
11/7/2015   67.85736847
```

Say I want to do a monthly rolling average - obviously not every day is filled in, and some data points will only have themselves in that month. I've tried to do that with AVERAGEIFS like this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C$2:C$128,A$2:A$128,">A2-15",A$2:A$128,"<A2+15")
```

(I don't really care that a month isn't exactly 30 days - good enough for my purposes. Also, my data is in column C - there's a column with different unrelated data in B)

But I get `#VALUE!`. Any help? I'm not very experienced with Excel so I don't even really know how to debug this.

Comment: Assuming everything else works, you're not correctly referencing the cells.  Try `=AVERAGEIFS(C$2:C$128,A$2:A$128,">" & A2 & "-15",A$2:A$128,"<" & A2 & "+15")`

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks! I changed it to that but now I get a `#DIV/0!`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @fixer1234 I want a transformation such that every data point becomes the average of a window of 30 days surrounding it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930823/average-a-range-of-values-if-the-date-associated-with-it-falls-within-a-date-ran

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C$2:C$128,A$2:A$128,">="&A2-15,A$2:A$128,"<="&A2+15)
```